# In Rickshaw.js, is there a way to select data with mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a graph like the following:

http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/fixed.html

I'd like to be able to do some sort of "mouse drag selection" over a particular portion of the data, similar to how it's possible in this library:

http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/selection/index.html

How can I do this in Rickshaw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `examples/rangeselector.html` in fork https://github.com/VividCortex/rickshaw/tree/range-selection-tool

That's some sort of "mouse drag selection" that will keep you going.